# C# Method Name Expected error, using ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c#

I'm trying out threading and relatively new to it.

What I want to do is simply call a void on a different class passing in the parameter.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dtRow in urlTable.Rows)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin(dtRow)));
            }
        }

 public static void MasterCrawlBegin(DataRow dtRow)
    {
        if (dtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("$"))
        {
            linkGrabberwDates(dtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }
        else
        {
            NoDatesCarCrawler(dtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }

    }
```

Also, my intent is to have 4 threads going while each of those threads only pass in 1 datarow.  I dont think how I have it now accomplishes that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted this work work the way you're trying to do it, you'd have to make your `MasterCrawlBegin` method take an `object` as its parameter, then pass in a reference to the method itself:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin));
```

But it's easier to take advantage of closures and lambda functions, rather than resorting to the ParameterizedThreadStart class.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin(dtRow));
```

#### Update

After reading your comments on another answer, I think you may benefit from learning about .NET 4's [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx). You could parallelize a whole collection in a pretty optimal way like this:

```
urlTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsParallel()
    .ForAll(MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin);
```

This will let the framework figure out how many threads it thinks it should use. If you want more control, there are ways of fine-tuning, like ensuring that exactly four concurrent threads get used:

```
urlTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .ForAll(MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin);
```

Comment: and then you start it with thread.Start() correct, however when i do this nothing starts

Comment: @Mike you need to call the `thread.Start` - this is the correct/best solution, parametrized is a bit obsolete.

Comment: @Mike: It looks like PLINQ may actually be a better fit for what you're trying to do. Check out my update.

Answer (score 1):

To easily accomplish this, also with the stuff related to data row parsing you can access just a global variable and avoid passing it like a parameter. If by *parsing* you mean **read** the data from `DataRow`, you safe. If you need to write to, it's better to implement some locking/sync mechanism, even if you're completely sure **now** that one thread *always* acess its own row.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Also such code should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dtRow in urlTable.Rows)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(MasterCrawlerClass.MasterCrawlBegin);
                thread.Start(dtRow);
            }
        }

 public static void MasterCrawlBegin(object data)
    {
        var dtRow = (DataRow)data;

        if (dtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("$"))
        {
            linkGrabberwDates(dtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }
        else
        {
            NoDatesCarCrawler(dtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }

    }
```

Comment: do you mean var dtRow = (DataRow)data;?

Comment: Yes, of course. Changed it in a minute after posting the answer.

Comment: let me ask you this, how do i run 4 threads to go through all of the datarows?  Meaning  if i have a 1000 datarows and I want only 4 threads possing 4 rows at a time how do you accomplish that

Comment: You'll have to use synchronization between your 4 threads to control the number of read items at once. For example, ManualResetEvent class.